# How to implement redo statement (as in Perl and Ruby) in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, redo, control-structure

Code that requires `break` statements or `continue` statements in other languages can be done with `block` & `return-from` or `catch` & `throw` in Common Lisp and Emacs Lisp. Then there is code that requires `redo` statements, or at least best written with `redo`. And `redo` statements don't have to be about loops. How can I do `redo` in Lisp?

If there was a `redo` equivalent in Lisp, I think it would work like this: special form `with-redo` which takes a symbol and forms, and `redo` which takes a symbol. The form `(with-redo 'foo BODY-FORMS...)` may contain `(redo 'foo)` in its BODY-FORMS, and `(redo 'foo)` transfers control back to the beginning of BODY-FORMS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Common Lisp:

```
(tagbody
   start
   (do-something)
   (go start))


(dotimes (i some-list)
  redo
  (when (some-condition-p)
    (go redo))
  (some-more))
```

Comment: It should be added that some macros (like `dotimes`, or more generally all looping macros starting with `do`) implicitly enclose their bodies  in a tagbody.  That is what is demonstrated in the second example above.

Answer (score 5):

[Rainer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17361084/1281433) illustrates the use of [`tagbody`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_tagbod.htm) which is probably the easiest way to implement this kind of construct (a particular kind of `goto`, or unconditional jump).  I thought it'd be nice to point out that if you don't want to use an explicit tagbody, or an implicit tagbody provided by one of the standard constructs, you can also create a `with-redo` just as you suggested.  The only difference in this implementation is that we won't quote the tag, since they're not evaluted in `tagbody`, and being consistent with the other constructs is nice too.

```
(defmacro with-redo (name &body body)
  `(macrolet ((redo (name)
                `(go ,name)))
     (tagbody
        ,name
        ,@body)))

CL-USER> (let ((x 0))
           (with-redo beginning
             (print (incf x))
             (when (< x 3)
               (redo beginning))))
1 
2 
3 
; => NIL
```

Now this is actually a [leaky abstraction](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html), since the `body` could define other labels for the implicit `tagbody`, and could use `go` instead of `redo`, and so on.  This might be desirable;  lots of the built in iteration constructs (e.g., [`do`, `do*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_do.htm)) use an implicit `tagbody`, so it might be OK.  But, since you're also adding your own control flow operator, `redo`, you might want to make sure that it can only be used with tags defined by `with-redo`.  In fact, while [Perl's `redo`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/redo.html) can be used with or without a label, [Ruby's `redo`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm) doesn't appear to allow a label.  The label-less cases allow behavior of jumping back to the innermost enclosing loop (or, in our case, the innermost `with-redo`).  We can address the leaky abstraction, as well as the ability to nest `redo`s at the same time.

```
(defmacro with-redo (&body body)
  `(macrolet ((redo () `(go #1=#:hidden-label)))
     (tagbody
        #1#
        ((lambda () ,@body)))))
```

Here we've defined a tag for use with `with-redo` that other things shouldn't know about (and can't find out unless they macroexpand some `with-redo` forms, and we've wrapped the `body` in a `lambda` function, which means that, e.g., a symbol in the `body` is a form to be evaluated, not a tag for `tagbody`.  Here's an example showing that `redo` jumps back to the nearest lexically enclosing `with-redo`:

```
CL-USER> (let ((i 0) (j 0))
           (with-redo
             (with-redo 
               (print (list i j))
               (when (< j 2)
                 (incf j)
                 (redo)))
             (when (< i 2)
               (incf i)
               (redo))))

(0 0) 
(0 1) 
(0 2) 
(1 2) 
(2 2) 
; => NIL
```

Of course, since you can define `with-redo` on your own, you can make the decisions about which design you want to adopt.  Perhaps you like the idea of `redo` taking no arguments (and disguising a `go` with a secret label, but `with-redo` still being an implicit tagbody so that you can define other tags and jump to them with `go`;  you can adapt the code here to do just that, too.

#### Some notes on implementation

This this answer has generated a few comments, I wanted to make a couple more notes about the implementation.  Implementing `with-redo` with labels is pretty straightfoward, and I think that all the answers posted address it;  the label-less case is a bit tricker.

First, the use of a local macrolet is a convenience that will get us warnings with `redo` is used outside of some lexically enclosing `with-redo`.   E.g., in SBCL:

```
CL-USER> (defun redo-without-with-redo ()
           (redo))
; in: DEFUN REDO-WITHOUT-WITH-REDO
;     (REDO)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: REDO
```

Second, the use of `#1=#:hidden-label` and `#1#` means that the go tag for redoing is an uninterned symbol (which lessens the likelihood that the abstraction leaks), but also is the same symbol across *expansions* of `with-redo`.  In the following snippet `tag1` and `tag2` are the go-tags from two different expansions of `with-redo`.

```
(let* ((exp1 (macroexpand-1 '(with-redo 1 2 3)))
       (exp2 (macroexpand-1 '(with-redo a b c))))
  (destructuring-bind (ml bndgs (tb tag1 &rest rest)) exp1   ; tag1 is the go-tag
    (destructuring-bind (ml bndgs (tb tag2 &rest rest)) exp2
      (eq tag1 tag2))))
; => T
```

An alternative implementation of `with-redo` that uses a fresh `gensym` for each macroexpansion does not have this guarantee.  For instance, consider `with-redo-gensym`:

```
(defmacro with-redo-gensym (&body body)
  (let ((tag (gensym "REDO-TAG-")))
    `(macrolet ((redo () `(go ,tag)))
       (tagbody 
          ,tag
          ((lambda () ,@body))))))

(let* ((exp1 (macroexpand-1 '(with-redo-gensym 1 2 3)))
       (exp2 (macroexpand-1 '(with-redo-gensym a b c))))
  (destructuring-bind (ml bndgs (tb tag1 &rest rest)) exp1
    (destructuring-bind (ml bndgs (tb tag2 &rest rest)) exp2
      (eq tag1 tag2))))
; => NIL
```

Now, it's worth asking whether this makes a practical difference, and if so, in which cases, and is it a difference for the better or the worse?  Quite frankly, I'm not entirely sure.

If you were performing some complicated code manipulation *after* the inner macroexpansion of an `(with-redo ...)` form, *form<sub>1</sub>*, so that `(redo)` has already been turned into `(go #1#)`, it means that moving the `(go #1#)` into the body of another `(with-redo ...)` form, *form<sub>2</sub>*, it will still have the effect of restarting an iteration in *form<sub>2</sub>*.  In my mind, this makes it more like a [`return`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_return.htm) that could be transported from a `block` *b<sub>1</sub>* into a different `block` *b<sub>2</sub>*, with the only difference it now returns from *b<sub>2</sub>* instead of *b<sub>1</sub>*.  I *think* that this is desirable, since we're trying to treat label-less `with-redo` and `redo` as primitive control structures.

Comment: Interesting use of the #: read macro and #1# to create a fresh uninterned symbol that can be referenced later. I've never seen this before. I can't decide if I like this better compared to the typical (let (foo (gensym)) `(...)) approach that I've seen much more often. Any reason why one is better/more appropriate to prevent variable capture, or is it simply a matter of style to use one or the other?

Comment: @ClaytonStanley Using an ubintenred (read) symbol allows for good-looking code, but can cause some confusion when looking at expanded macros (if you expand this `(with-redo .... (with-redo ...) ...)` it is not clear which `#:hidden-label` is which, but using the LET idiom and `(gensym 'hidden-label)` should lead to the uninterned symbols being named different things (#:hidden-symbol0001, ...).

Comment: @Vatine Right. That's what threw me off at first with the #:foo technique. I know that you cannot rely on print statements of symbols to determine if they are eq, but at least with the gensym technique you get some visual feedback that says that they are probably not eq.

Comment: @Vatine @ClaytonStanley In this case though, we want the _same_ uninterned symbol across _all_ expansions of `with-redo`, so that we can reliably say that `redo` brings us back to the lexically enclosing innermost `with-redo`.  An alternative would be `(let ((hidden-tag (gensym …))) (defmacro  …))`, but that's got a top-level let which I find a little ugly (but it's not really a problem), or `(defvar *hidden-tag* …)`, but then we've defined something that might draw someone's attention (but that's not really a problem either;  if you poke the internals, you might break something).

Answer (score 1):

**Update: Emacs 24.4 (soon to be released) has tagbody. cl-lib that comes with Emacs 24.4 includes cl-tagbody.**

For a dialect of Lisp which doesn't have tagbody, one can still implement redo as long as the dialect has a catch/throw equivalent.

For Emacs Lisp:

```
;; with-redo version 0.1
(defmacro with-redo (tag &rest body)
  "Eval BODY allowing jumps using `throw'.
TAG is evalled to get the tag to use; it must not be nil.
Then the BODY is executed.
Within BODY, a call to `throw' with the same TAG and a non-nil VALUE causes a jump to the beginning of BODY.
A call to `throw' with the same TAG and nil as VALUE exits BODY and this `with-redo'.
If no throw happens, `with-redo' returns the value of the last BODY form."
  (declare (indent 1))
  (let ((ret (make-symbol "retval")))
    `(let (,ret)
       (while
           (catch ,tag
             (setq ,ret (progn ,@body))
             nil))
       ,ret)))
(defun redo (symbol)
  (throw symbol t))
```

Example of use (all examples are in Emacs Lisp):

```
(with-redo 'question
  (let ((name (read-string "What is your name? ")))
    (when (equal name "")
      (message "Zero length input. Please try again.")
      (beep)
      (sit-for 1)
      (redo 'question))
    name))
```

Same example written as a mid-test loop instead:

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(let (name)
  (cl-loop do
           (setq name (read-string "What is your name? "))
           while
           (equal name "")
           do
           (message "Zero length input. Please try again.")
           (beep)
           (sit-for 1))
  name)
```

Same example written as an infinite loop with a throw instead:

```
(let (name)
  (catch 'question
    (while t
      (setq name (read-string "What is your name? "))
      (unless (equal name "")
        (throw 'question name))
      (message "Zero length input. Please try again.")
      (beep)
      (sit-for 1))))
```

---

Implementing `with-lex-redo-anon` and `lex-redo`, where `(lex-redo)` causes a jump to the beginning of body of the textually/lexically innermost `with-lex-redo-anon` form:

```
;; with-lex-redo-anon version 0.1
(require 'cl-lib)
(defmacro with-lex-redo-anon (&rest body)
  "Use with `(lex-redo)'."
  (let ((tag (make-symbol "lex-redo-tag"))
        (ret (make-symbol "retval")))
    `(cl-macrolet ((lex-redo () '(cl-return-from ,tag t)))
       (let (,ret)
         (while
             (cl-block ,tag
               (setq ,ret (progn ,@body))
               nil))
         ,ret))))
```

Example test:

```
(let ((i 0) (j 0))
  (with-lex-redo-anon
    (with-lex-redo-anon
      (print (list i j))
      (when (< j 2)
        (incf j)
        (lex-redo)))
    (when (< i 2)
      (incf i)
      (lex-redo))))
```

Same output as in another answer.

Comment: In Common Lisp, `catch` and `throw` have dynamic connection (`throw` just needs to happen _while_ a corresponding `catch` is higher up on the stack), whereas `tagbody` and `go` are lexical.  E.g., `(flet ((foo () (go away))) (tagbody away (foo)))` is an error, but `(flet ((foo () (throw 'away))) (catch 'away (foo)))` is OK.  With fresh symbols, a `catch`-based solution could work, but `redo` still needs the `tag` as an argument, which the question allowed, but is less like the label-less `redo`s of Perl and Ruby.  Can this be adapted to allow a label-less `redo` that always transfers to the…

Comment: …lexically innermost enclosing `with-redo`?

Comment: I added a definition of `with-lex-redo-anon` to the answer. This relies on lexical `cl-block` and `cl-return-from` which are implemented in `cl-lib` by using dynamical `catch` and `throw`. Not sure how `cl-lib` pulls that off, but they seem to work.